# React-aws-s3 installed but error 'Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-aws-s3''

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have ran `yarn add react-aws-s3` several times and it is in my package.json file: `"react-aws-s3": "^1.5.0",`but for some reason I am still getting an error on this line: `import S3 from 'react-aws-s3';` that reads:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-aws-s3'. 'c:/Users/e096752/Documents/Cole's Git Repos/CyberpunkAPI/frontend/node_modules/react-aws-s3/dist/react-aws-s3.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/react-aws-s3` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'react-aws-s3';`ts(7016)
```

So then I tried running `yarn add @types/react-aws-s3` but got this error:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types%2freact-aws-s3: Not found".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\e096752\\Documents\\Cole's Git Repos\\CyberpunkAPI\\frontend\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.
```

It is also interesting to me that every time I have run either the install command or the add types command it has made me choose a version of react-router-dom which doesn't make much sense to me.

What is happening and what can I do to fix this probelm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no typings for the `react-aws-s3` in the [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) repo, so you cannot use the suggested command, but you can try the second suggestion: `add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing "declare module 'react-aws-s3';"`

or you can try disable `noImplicitAny` and/or `strict` options in your `tsconfig.json`, so compiler will not complain about it.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I would like to keep strict mode on if possible here so I'd really like to try your first option. Humor me for a moment and just act like I'm dumb; what exactly does this mean ````add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing "declare module 'react-aws-s3';"```` mean? How exactly do I do that? I'm sorry I've never used typescript before.

Comment: @grillowner69420 you need to create a new file for instance `react-aws-s3.d.ts` in any folder (`typings` as best practice), and put `declare module 'react-aws-s3';` text there . This will let typescript know that `react-aws-s3` is a module. But most probably just declaring a module will not help in strict mode, you will also have to define types which you’re using from the module:

Comment: But you know actually the `react-aws-s3` is written in typescript and it should go smooth, but the problem is that the owner of the package is not exporting typings for it, so I guess using the package `react-aws-s3-typescript` instead would solve your issue.

Comment: Yes using ````react-aws-s3-typescript```` did solve the problem. Thank you so much!